# Admob ad inside a RecyclerView. RecycleView scrolls automatically when ad gets loaded

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView inside which there is a `MEDIUM_RECTANGLE` ad. The RecyclerView scrolls automatically to the ad when the ad is loaded. I don't want this automatic scrolling to happen.

I saw a number of posts suggesting to **`Block Decsecdant's focusability`** on RecyclerView using (a)`RecyclerView#setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS)` and also tried (b)`AdView.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS)`.

Although (a) did fix that problem but a new problem occurred. You see, there are other `View`s inside that RecyclerView including some `EditText`s. After executing the (a) statement, editTexts also stopped taking focus. Therefore, I can't use that. Please suggest an alternate solution.